# Inject a bean into a manually instantiated class in spring

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

I've got some domain classes that I'm using. There is a requirement for logging in them, but it doesn't look like spring will allow you to inject a bean into a manually instantiated object. I don't want to have to pass the logger as a parameter to constructor because this logger is a bean that I'm autowiring into most of my classes. It looks a little bit like this:

```
public class MainClass {
    private Logger logger;
    public MainClass(Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }
    public void doThing() {
        //..do stuff
        DomainClass domainObject = new DomainClass(//params);
    }
}

public class DomainClass {
    //bunch of fields
    
    //field I want to autowire
    private Logger logger;
}

@Component
public class Logger {
    //stuff
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this without passing the logger as a parameter?

Comment: You can do it by getting beans out of ApplicationContext. Take a look here https://dzone.com/articles/autowiring-spring-beans-into-classes-not-managed-by-spring. Mind you this is not a good approach

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of great Java logging libraries that do not require you to drag the logger around. For example, the logging in SLF4J looks like this:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MainClass {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainClass.class);

    public MainClass() { }
    
    public void doThing(String userInput) {
        ...
        logger.info("Info message");
        logger.debug("Debug message");
        logger.error("Error message with an argument: {}", userInput);
        ...
    }
}
```

As you see, SLF4J does not require you to register the logger in the IoC container and instead relies on the static factory method `LoggerFactory.getLogger`.

I just can't emphasize how nice and configurable Java logging libraries are compared to any hand-written logger. I recommend you to use an existing and well established logging library, for example the combination SLF4J + Logback that Spring Boot uses by default.

If you can't use a third-party logging library for your use case, consider managing your `MainClass` and other classes like this in the IoC container together with the logger. This way you'll have the full power of Spring auto-wiring at your fingertips. Spring can't do anything about objects you create yourself. Spring operates only on the objects in its IoC container.

Comment: That's really good to know and I'll keep that in mind for future reference, but sadly I'm working on a corporate code base and I can't change the fact that our logger is managed by the spring container (it's actually based on SLF4J, but they made it a bean). The DomainClass is not in the container because it's just there so we do the processing we need to and then write it all out to JSON.